# Solving a system of equations with 3 unknown variables and only 2 formulas

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equations: y = x + 3, x = 2z - 35. I have tried plugging in x into the formula of y, but I still cannot solve it. Is it possible, and if so, how?

Comment: The best you can do is find $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ and vice-versa (i.e. rearrange for a variable in terms of the others). Since you only have two equations, the system has many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Given 3 unknowns and only formulas, the only solution is to narrow it down to a single formula, but you cannot reach numerical values for the variables. In this particular case, as you mentioned, plugging in x will get you y in terms of z.

Comment: Are you answering your own question or is there someone else replying to this post?